# Switch between two divs in JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am tring to switch between two divs (a small text area and a bigger form field..sort of like twitter). The divs belong to two different classes like

```
<div class = first onClick = "show();" >
```

```
<div class = second style = "display:none;">
contains a form that is supposed to redirect to some other .php page via the "action" field
</div>
```

I have the following javascript

```
function show()
{
        $(".second").fadeIn('5');
        $(".first").fadeOut('5');

}
```

When the form in the class = "second" is clicked however the page simply refreshes and div = "first" is displayed (instead of redirecting to the page that the form points to)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears there may be an error in the action? Could you post the form inside `<div class="second">`? The jQuery should really have nothing to do with where the link is directing to.

Comment: And where is the form, uhm? Pretty difficult to answer question on your form without showing it

Comment: sorry guys dumb mistake....the problem WAS in the form/form handler. I was accessing the data with GET but the data was sent with POST...maybe Fishz can add his comment as an answer so I can accept it....and i should probably get sleep lol

Comment: you want to submit second div form when first is clicked right? BTW define the classes inside the quotes.

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: You should delete this question, as it is nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there may be an error in the action. The jQuery should really have nothing to do with where the link is directing to.

The problem is likely the form inside `<div class="second">`.

Answer (score 0):

It works on here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NMMVB/

Comment: Try this-->http://jsfiddle.net/NMMVB/1/ ...it basically toggles but thats not the behavior i want... i would like the form which actually contains a redirect command...to actually redirect and not just come back to the same page

Comment: I dont get it, so you just want a redirect, or a toggle?